# mod_rewrite rule to replace a sub-string from a URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to do this:

I have an old URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dev-site/some-content-part-here
```

That I want to make into:

```
http://www.mysite.com/live/some-content-part-here
```

## Edit

*I found somebody voted down on my question. I dont know what thought drove him/her to that but actually the question really was not that silly! May be the downer did not understand why I asked this... it could be anything in his mind. But I want all readers, if you dont like question - please always try to communicate through comments and then if the question poster does not agree your changes, then down vote. Thanks.*

*And guys, thanks for editing.

Comment: Anything that split up the url in 2 parts? like take left side and right side of the url into some variables and then combine them with the "live"? like this $1/live/$2? Sorry I am not expert in these please dont mind if it seems a silly question. Thanks!

Comment: I found following working for me!

RewriteRule ^dev-site/(.*)$  live/$1  [R=301,NE,L]

Thanks

Comment: "I dont know what thought drove him/her to that" Answer: a lot of developers are know-it-all jerks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/dev-site/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/live/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that it *might* work if you only use `/live/$1` on the right hand side, but I'd do this to be sure.

I know you know this (since you've mentioned mod_rewrite), but for those that don't, you generally put this into the `.htaccess` file in the directory - either `dev-site` or root should work.

Comment: Maybe you need to enable mod_rewrite on your server @KMX